# ITextSharp Error while exporting GridView to PDF

Tags: c#, gridview, itext, export-to-pdf

I tried exporting a `GridView` to PDF. It gives the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.CellWrapper' to type 'iTextSharp.text.Paragraph'.

It throws the error here

```
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should disable sorting and paging before the databinding and parsing.

Here is the code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");

Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

GridView1.AllowPaging = false;     <----

GridView1.AllowSorting = false;    <----

GridView1.DataBind();

GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f,10f,10f,0f);

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

pdfDoc.Open();

htmlparser.Parse(sr);

pdfDoc.Close();

Response.Write(pdfDoc);

Response.End();
```